# Angular 5 Material Data Table Does Not Update On Sort

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-material

I've read through I don't know how many examples and to my knowledge I'm following the example correctly but the columns do not update when I click on a header.

-I have included MatSortModule in my app.module.ts

-I have included matSort on the mat-table

-I have included mat-sort-header on header-cells of the columns I want to be able to sort by (all of them)

-I have included @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort; and the corresponding

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

I don't see what else is left. Here is my code snippet:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="dataTable">

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <mat-header-cell 
            *matHeaderCellDef 
            fxLayout="row" 
            fxLayoutAlign="start center" 
            mat-sort-header
            class="clickable"
        > 
            Product Name 
        </mat-header-cell>

        <mat-cell 
            *matCellDef="let item" 
            class="table-cell-content"
        > 
            {{item.name}} 
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
```

...

```
defaultData: Array<Object> = null;
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.defaultData);

@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

constructor(private getDataService: GetDataService) { 
  this.getDataService.getData()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.defaultData = data;
      this.dataSource.data = this.defaultData;
    },
    err => console.log(err));
}
```

...

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this the only table on this component? There is a weird way you have to do it if there are multiple tables within the same component.

Comment: Yes it is the only table. What looks weird?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of that might be your issue here is that you probably shouldn't be assigning the data directly to the `.data` property of the `.dataSource` property. It is possible that modifying this property directly is causing the sort to not understand which data it is supposed to be working on in the first place, but I can't say that for sure (just taking a shot in the dark here). Creating a `new MatTableDataSource()` reference should trigger the reactivity of the Observable sequences that are built into the CDK Table structures, which should allow for the sorting to happen.

```js
constructor(private getDataService: GetDataService) { 
  this.getDataService.getData()
    .subscribe(data => {
      // Your code:
      // this.defaultData = data;
      // this.dataSource.data = this.defaultData;
      
      // What I would do:
      this.defaultData = data;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
    },
    err => console.log(err));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can sort the data with underscorejs and the material table will be refreshed or create a new instance with the MatTableDataSource.

```
this.myDataSource = _.sortBy(initialData, 'fieldToSort' );
```

or

```
this.myDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(initialData);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, even though I declared

```js
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<MyRowEntity>
```

I was still setting it to an array (which would require an explicit call to matTableChild.renderRows())

```js
// renderRows not called automatically onSortChange
dataSource = [{name: 'hello'}, {name: 'world'}]
```

**Solution:**

```js
// renderRows called automatically onSortChange
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(myRowEntities);
```